# What is the probability that Alice and Bob live in the same city?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

**Problem**

There are $d$ different cities. Last year Alice and Bob did NOT live in the same city. The probability that Alice moved to a new city since last year is $m$. This probability is the same for Bob. Each city has the same probability of being chosen. Let's assume that the movement of Bob and Alice (as well as their choice of destination) are independent.

**What is the probability that Alice and Bob live in the same city this year?**

**My Thoughts**

*Possibility 1*

One moved but not the other. The one who moved went to the city of the onw who did not move. This happens with probability $2m(1-m)\frac{1}{d-1}$

*Possibility 2*

Both moved and end up in the same city. For this to be true, the one who moved must go in any city other than the one where the other was at first place and the second one has to go to the same city. I think this should occur with probability $m^2\frac{d-2}{d-1}\frac{1}{d-1}$.

*My Answer*

The probability that Alice and Bob still live in the same city is

$$2m(1-m)\frac{1}{d-1} + m^2\frac{d-2}{d-1}\frac{1}{d-1} = \frac{m(2d-md-2)}{(d-1)^2} $$

Is it correct?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: The problem statement is a bit imprecise. For your calculation, we need to assume that if $X$ decides to move, all choices of new city are equally likely. Also, please check your simplification.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is my statement more clear now? I am not sure what you mean by "check your simplification". Thanks

Comment: You have two factors of $d-1$ in the second term on the left, so that is the common denominator

Comment: @Remi.b: Yes, with equiprobable it is good. In the simplification, there is a denominator issue, basically a typo. There may also be a numerator issue. Also, given the risks, why simplify? I liked the original sum better.

Comment: Oh I saw my mistake. Thanks it is fixed now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun, here's another solution. Instead of saying that each person moved with probability $m$, we could say that with probability $m\cdot\frac d{d-1}$ they chose one of the $d$ cities to live in and with probability $1-m\cdot\frac d{d-1}$ they stayed put. The probability that they now live in the same city is $\frac1d$ times the probability that at least one of them made a choice, i.e.

$$
\frac1d\left(1-\left(1-m\cdot\frac d{d-1}\right)^2\right)=\frac{m(2d-md-2)}{(d-1)^2}\;,
$$

which I believe coincides with your result if you correct the mistake in the last step.

Of course this isn't quite rigorous for the case $m\cdot\frac d{d-1}\gt1$, but since it's really just a rearrangement of the calculation, the formula must be the same in that case.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I also fixed my mistake during simplification. +1

Comment: just for fun, I tried to see what is derivative of the expression by $m$. I would expect to see it always positive, because as $m$ is lower more chance they will both stay in their cities. However it is not the case. if $m > \frac{d-1}{d}$ the derivative is negative... which I'm not sure I have explanation for this.

Comment: @d_e: It just so happens that this is easier to see in my setup: $m=\frac{d-1}d$ is the value at which the expression being squared is zero. This maximum occurs because of a trade-off of two effects: The lower $m$, the more likely that neither moves; but the higher $m$, the more likely that they unnecessarily both move and one moves to the city that the other moved away from. The maximum occurs when the changes in these two effects are equal.

Comment: @joriki, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: For those interested, there is a follow-up question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875429/markov-chain-and-forward-and-backward-probabilities-with-alice-and-bob).